# Create copy function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scripting

Hey am  new web developer and am working on a project. I am working on a quote website. In that website you can copy the quotes.

***To understand the question clearly Please visit my CodePen or run the below code***
https://codepen.io/Akash11166666/pen/JjRzqzp
Or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="Find Status/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hindinj.html">caeman</a>
  <div class="mainStatus">
   <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="allquotes"></div>
<div class="pagable-status">
  <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
  <div class="pagable-actions">
    <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
    <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
    <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
    <select name="page-size">
      <option>20</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
</div>

<script>
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.status}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {
  // here we are making a network call to your api
  const response = await fetch('Find Status/stat.php');
  
  // then converting it to json instead of a readable stream
  const data = await response.json();
  
  return data;
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {
        const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')
            .childNodes[0].textContent;
        const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
        textArea.value = quote;
        document.body.appendChild(textArea);
        textArea.select();
        document.execCommand('Copy');
        textArea.remove();
    }
  },
  false
);

main();
 
  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see there are copy button for every quote (they are created from Javascript). They work perfectly but we cannot know is the text is copied. I needed a `<span>Copied</span>` to be visible when the copy button is clicked without inserting the `<span>` element in html that is creating it from Javascript. I tried to create span elements from Javascript but it is not working.

```
 copyAlertElement = document.createElement('span');
    copyAlertElement.classList.add('status-copy-alert')
    let copyMessage = document.createTextNode('Copied!');
    copyAlertElement.appendChild(copyMessage);

    element.appendChild(copyAlertElement);
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.removeChild(copyAlertElement);
    }, 700);
```

***Again I will tell my problem that, I need a span element to be visible when the copy button is clicked. Without inserting span element directly to html that is, creating it from javascript same as the copy button for each quote.***

I heartly thanks those who answer this question

Comment: The only option you have that doesn't involve inserting an element is [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). Generally, to display something, it needs to be a part of the page even if it's temporarily so.

Comment: Reposted many times [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830179/how-to-copy-button-in-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804598/creat-copy-button-for-json-data), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840527/create-copy-function-in-javascript), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832705/create-copy-button-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```js
element.appendChild(copyAlertElement);
setTimeout(function() {
  element.removeChild(copyAlertElement);
}, 700);
```

You can use append instead.

May I know the element tag that you are trying to append?

Comment: I needed the span to be visible when a copy button is clicked please visit my CodePen